# Devise + Omniauth + Rememberable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, omniauth, remember-me

I followed the tutorial on the github devise wiki : 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview

So I've created a omniauth controller for the callbacks, but it is bypassing the normal sessions controller and so, the rememberable cookie is not set.

What is the best way for me to fix that ?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : The Gist from my controller code : https://gist.github.com/913164
So I think the sign in an redirect just set the session cookie, not the rememberable one.

EDIT 2 : I also have a backdoor for dev sign in and avoid FB connect on my local machine :

```
  def backdoor
        if RAILS_ENV == "development"
            @user = User.first
            @user.remember_me!
            sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
        end
  end
```

Doesn't work either, so I might have a problem somewhere else.

Comment: I don't believe you will be able to use the rememberable cookie using omniauth as oauth is a session based authentication.

Comment: Did you see [this SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475726/devise-and-omniauth-remembering-oauth)?

Comment: Well from omniauth I'm asking for a persistent token, so I save it and create a user, so I do have a "real" devise user to remember.

Comment: I did, it just doesn't seems to work, I'll add a gist with my controller to show what I'm using.

Comment: My mistake, I thought this was another answer on stackoverflow that I read already. I'll try that out in a few days, thank you !

Comment: Alright, it the answer does not fix my problem.

Comment: Did it or did it not fix your problem?

Comment: Sorry, it did partially. I was missing this: `@user.remember_me = true`

Comment: @rnaud can you answer your own question and accept it so we can clear it out of the queue of unanswered questions please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn this is old, sorry to let this stay here this long.

From my answer in the comments apparently in 11', I forgot to add this:

```
@user.remember_me = true
```

Now let's close this.