# Rails Devise redirecting authenticated user to a specific path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth-facebook

### Problem

With Devise the `user` should be redirected to the `edit_user_registration_path` of the Devise controller `registrations#edit` action when already logged in.

### Description

In the `routes.rb` the **root** is set as `root :to => 'main#welcome'`. The User is allways redirected to this page, even when already logged in.

Thanks a lot
Fabrizio

Comment: if you have not seen this yet, it may help you out, https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview

Comment: @RockwellRice Thanks, yes I read it. I am searching online for bugs, It is a lost session so I am testing the following solutions 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816294/omniauthfacebook-lost-session

Comment: @RockwellRice I am thinking of accepting your answer. For this specific issue I will create another question. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you are looking for is a way to redirect the user to some place after he logs in. This should do it. Put this in `app/controllers/application_controller.rb` and place in the path you want to take the user to

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    edit_user_registration_path # or any other path needed
  end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I need to redirect the user independently from the Sign In. I already edited that `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` and It worked, but right now I am trying to redirect him when he is already signed in.

Answer (score 1):

Devise provides the `user_signed_in?`  method.

This would be the `welcome` method in you `main_controller.rb`

```
def welcome 

    if user_signed_in?
        redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    else
        // put other page in here
    end        
end
```

Comment: I think your answer is the correct one. My user_signed_in? is always false, even after sign in. I tested and read the value both with facebook omniauth and normal sign_in/sign_up . Thanks

Comment: you could try "if current_user"  instead, not really a fix but could at least I get it going in the right direction and help debug.  If that is still false even after sign in then something is wrong with the implementation and you should look at the database to see what records are being set.

Comment: Thanks, I need to correct myself. The `user_signed_in?` method does **not work** when I log in with **facebook omniauth**, while It works with normal users. I tried with `current_user`. When I log in with facebook omniauth, it will redirect me to my profile. If I visit then localhost:3000 with send me to main#welcome and triggers `if current_user` with `current_user = nil`

Comment: I would update the original post to mention omniauth.

Answer (score 0):

It could be misleading, but the user is signed in by devise after [sign up](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise/RegistrationsController#sign_up-instance_method) 
method called inside [Devise::RegistrationsController#create](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L24)

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
    # omitted code
    resource.save
    sign_up(resource_name, resource)
```

which sign_in() the user

```
def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
  sign_in(resource_name, resource)
end
```

so the method to be enhanced is

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  edit_user_registration_path
end
```