# Devise Omniauth-Facebook rememberable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth-facebook

### Problem

I have **Devise Omniauth-Facebook** authentication. The log in with facebook works, but the Session is lost when the user goes to `localhost:3000`.
I have the following **GEMs**:

```
Devise 4.2.0
Rails 5
omniauth 1.4.0
omniauth-facebook 4.0.0
omniauth-oauth2 1.4.0
```

### Description

The Session works correctly for users not authenticated with Omniauth-Facebook,

This is my `devise.rb` omniauth-facebook **settings**:

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET", callback_url: "http://127.0.0.1:3000/users/auth/facebook/callback", scope: 'public_profile, email', image_size: 'large', provider_ignores_state: true
```

I already tried the following solution that did not work:

1. turning off protect_from_forgery
2. OmniAuth.config.full_host = "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
3. Following the accepted solution of Jeroen van Dijk at the following post:
   [Devise and OmniAuth remembering OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475726/devise-and-omniauth-remembering-oauth)
   For this solution, in my rake routes I do not have the path `user_oauth_connect_path`, even if I added the route in `routes.rb`. I also think this is not the solution to my problem because I have Devise 4.2.0 and Rails 5
4. @user.remember_me = true

All the previous solutions were taken from the following stackoverflow discussions:

[Omniauth+Facebook lost session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816294/omniauthfacebook-lost-session)

[Devise and OmniAuth remembering OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475726/devise-and-omniauth-remembering-oauth)

The code is the standard one included in the guides from github of *Devise* and *omniauth-facebook*
Thanks a lot for your help
Fabrizio Bertoglio

Comment: I just found this discussion, right now the functionality is working fine. If I will try to implement this solution I will post the answer. https://coderwall.com/p/bsfitw/ruby-on-rails-4-authentication-with-facebook-and-omniauth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is the solution to my problem? Facebook login right now works and If the session is not stored, the user can login back again without problems. I did not have any more experiences about losing the session so I am not taking so much interest in this issue.

> Notice that Devise's RegistrationsController by default calls User.new_with_session before building a resource. This means that, if we need to copy data from session whenever a user is initialized before sign up, we just need to implement new_with_session in our model. Here is an example that copies the facebook email if available:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

> Finally, if you want to allow your users to cancel sign up with Facebook, you can redirect them to cancel_user_registration_path. This will remove all session data starting with devise. and the new_with_session hook above will no longer be called.

[Omniauth Facebook Gihub page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview)