# Omniauth Session expires when browser is closed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, authentication, omniauth

In my rails 3 app I use Omniauth for the user authentication part (fb/twitter).

Actually I follow this:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/wiki/Tutorial

But,
when I close the browser session expires and I need to login again.
How can I keep the session for returning users?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: unclear: does this happen in your local environment/browser only? How does your test environment deal with HTTP cookies?

Comment: after login the session_controller stores user_id: session[:user_id] = user.id  https://github.com/RailsApps/rails3-mongoid-omniauth/blob/master/app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb

Comment: Can't really tell what happens in your application, but maybe you want to look into the cookie lifetime and other settings around rails seession cookies: http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/HowtoChangeSessionOptions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) offers this functionality through its Rememberable module. OmniAuth integrates easily with it through the (you'd never guess it) OmniAuth module. It's even mentioned in the second link you posted!

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview) the Devise wiki page about integrating with OmniAuth.

Comment: Vic, did you have trouble with it?

Comment: Not exactly trouble. I think that there’s no need to use Devise.
All I wish is to have my users sign in using a service provider’s account (such as Twitter or Facebook)..

Comment: Finally I combined devise with omniauth!

Answer (score 9):

What you want is not difficult, you only have to set a permanent cookie when the session is created and then retrieve this value when you set the current user.

In your `ApplicationController`, just change your `current_user` method to:

```
def current_user
  return unless cookies.signed[:permanent_user_id] || session[:user_id]
  begin
    @current_user ||= User.find(cookies.signed[:permanent_user_id] || session[:user_id])
  rescue Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound
    nil
  end
end
```

And in your `SessionsController`, modify your `create` to set the cookie if user wants to:

```
def create
  auth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  user = User.where(:provider => auth['provider'], 
                    :uid => auth['uid']).first || User.create_with_omniauth(auth)
  session[:user_id] = user.id
  cookies.permanent.signed[:permanent_user_id] = user.id if user.really_wants_to_be_permanently_remembered
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Signed in!"
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I combined devise and my problem solved!

Comment: You really should not be using the user_id in the signed cookie, the proper way would be to create a remember_me token in your user model, save that in the permanent cookie and when you don't have a current session, you create a new one by looking up the remember_me token. The tokens are harder to guess than changing your uid if a hacker figures out how to get around the cookie signing (its been done before).

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure the cookie policy that your rails app follows does have sensible settings for your use case (see the link in my comment above). All I can imagine right now (knowing what I know, sitting where I sit) is that the cookie(s) ha(s/ve) properties that are suboptimal/undesirable in your context.

Please check the cookie settings in a browser debug/development tool such as firebug, firecookie or the chrome development tools.

Sorry, that's all I can come up with given my knowledge of the problem. Feel free to contact me again with more details on your cookie- and testing-setup.

My 2Cents.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But as you can see here it's not a cookie problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475726/devise-and-omniauth-remembering-oauth

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it works for me:

```
def google_oauth2
  @user = User.from_google(google_params)

  if @user.persisted?
    @user.remember_me = true
    sign_in @user
    ........
  end
end
```

[There is another way to do it](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/Omniauthable,-sign-out-action-and-rememberable)